# Printing JQuery cookie data to console, using cookie plugin

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am currently trying to store a variable userScore in the cookie userScoreCookie using the JQuery cookie plugin. When i console.log the contents of the data printed is 'undefined'. What is causing this?

```js
var cookieValue;
var userScore = 0;
$.cookie('userScoreCookie', 'userScore', {path: '/',expires: 365});
cookieValue = $.cookie("userScoreCookie");
console.log("cookie score: " + cookieValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

Comment: it is working fine with me.

Comment: @AnilPanwar it turned out to be a problem with locally storing chrome cookies. a change to firefox fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome cannot use cookies while the page is being locally hosted, changing to firefox to test the cookies fixed this

Answer (score 2):

Paste the below to the link to check it http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
          var cookieValue;
var userScore = 0;
$.cookie('userScoreCookie', "test");
cookieValue = $.cookie("userScoreCookie");
console.log("cookie score: " + cookieValue );
alert(cookieValue )
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click me</p>


</body>
</html>
```